# How to correlate textboxes to images in Angular?

Tags: angular, click, gallery, document

I build a gallery which contains a lot of objects of the type image + text. Only one text box is shown at once. By clicking on image the corresponding textbox is shown. At the moment I try to use the code below which has at least two problems:

```
<div class="Container" [id]="id">
  <img [id]="id" id="t_1" src={{t1.jpg}} (click) ="showtext($event)">
  <img [id]="id" id="t_2" src={{t2.jpg}} (click) ="showtext($event)">
</div>

<div *ngIf="t_1" class="text" id="team_text_1" [id]="id" >{{team_text_1}}</div>
<div *ngIf="t_2" class="text" id="team_text_3" [id]="id" >{{team_text_2}}</div>

showMember(event){
  document.getElementById(event.target.id).classList.add('visible');
}
```

- the second class "id="t_1" won't be see because of the first one
- even if seen the same id appears 2 times which shouldn't happen
  _ scalability problem, because using this method with hundreds of images is very time expensive

Any ideas how to improve / fi my approach?

Thank you!

Comment: The source is same for both images.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for the reply! No, it's not, I changed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User,make it in Angular aproach.

First define an array of object with url and text, and a variable

```
text:string="";
data:any[]=[
      {url:"t1.jpg",text:"image 1"},
      {url:"t2.jpg",text:"image 2"}
]
```

After use ngFor like

```
<div class="Container" [id]="id">
  <img *ngFor="let item of data" [src]="item.url" (click) ="text=item.text">
</div>
<!--here show the variable "text"-->
<div class="text">{{text}}</div>
```

Angular "philosophy" is make possible the relation the view (the .html) and the model (variables in the .ts). Of course you can use like an old .html and javascript, but you loose the power of Angular